# Как расположить одно окно по центру другого

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

**У меня есть окно в котором расположена кнопка. При нажатии на эту кнопку у меня открывается ещё одно окно, но оно бывает расположено далеко от основного. Как сделать так, чтобы при открытии второго окна, оно располагалось по центру основного?** 
[image: Пример]

Comment: Добавьте вопрос минимальный пример. Например, то окно с кнопкой, при клике на которую открывается окно, а то каждый желающий помочь будет этот же код писать :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Тут собраны все варианты, показанные ниже.](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5799d6d0180b4108b8873ad3ce02289d12b05e78/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/create_child_window_by_center.py#L11)

---

Если при создании окна указывать ему ссылку на родителя, то новое окно появится по центру родителя, попробуйте:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        pb = QPushButton('Click!')
        pb.clicked.connect(self._create_new_window)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(pb)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def _create_new_window(self):
        # Указываем родителя и то, что виджет должен появиться как окно, а не внутри родительского виджета
        widget = QWidget(self, flags=Qt.Window)
        widget.resize(100, 100)
        widget.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.resize(400, 400)
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

---

Или можно самостоятельно рассчитать центр, например:

```
    def _create_new_window(self):
        widget = QWidget(self, flags=Qt.Window)
        widget.resize(100, 100)

        pos = self.geometry().center() - widget.rect().center()
        widget.move(pos)

        widget.show()
```

Либо (`from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint`):

```
        x = (self.geometry().width() - widget.width()) // 2
        y = (self.geometry().height() - widget.height()) // 2
        pos = self.mapToGlobal(QPoint(x, y))
        widget.move(pos)
```

---

[Еще такой вариант:](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/43158-How-to-center-main-window-on-screen?p=302248#post302248)

```
    def _create_new_window(self):
        widget = QWidget(self, flags=Qt.Window)
        widget.resize(200, 100)

        widget.setGeometry(QStyle.alignedRect(Qt.LeftToRight, Qt.AlignCenter, widget.size(), self.geometry()))
        widget.show()
```

Comment: Дело в том, что оба окна находятся в разных классах. И все ответы выше не помогли...

Comment: @djimbosfan, передаете ссылку класса одного виджета, другому. И в вашем коде, и в моем будет тот же код, просто приспособьте его. А так, мой ответ соответствует вашему вопросу, окно создается по центру. Не можете переделать свой код, то, как я ранее просил в комментарии, добавьте в вопрос минимальный пример и я покажу как сделать